# Lagrangian Floer (co)homology, Novikov coverings and exact symplectic manifolds

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, floer-homology, lagrangian-submanifolds

I started reading the book *"Lagrangian intersection Floer theory anomaly and obstruction"*, and there are a couple of details and assumptions in the definition of the Novikov covering that I would like to clarify. (I will follow the notation that they use in the book )

First is why do we need the actual use of the Novikov covering? With this I mean why are we asking for two conditions on that is for the integrals of the symplectic areas to be the same , I guess this makes sense so that the action functional is well-defined, but wouldn't this happen in the universal cover since the symplectic form is closed? I guess I don't understand why we need/want the extra assumption $I_{\mu}(\bar w \# w´)=0$. Will it be for the Maslov index of a point $[l_p,w]$ to be well-defined ? (At least it's the only thing I could see that it's useful for).

Then I am interested in symplying this and consider just exact symplectic manifolds $(M,d\lambda)$. Now here we are able to define the action functional in $\Omega(L_0,L_1)$ and still get that the intersection points are the critical points of this action functional.Just define $A(\gamma)=\int_{0}^{1}\gamma^* \lambda_{can}$.

But then how is the index of a critical point $p$ defined ? We could use the more general definition  that they talk about but then we would to pick a path $l_0$ and an homotopy class $[w]$ ,so I am wondering if this will be equal to something simpler and more intuitive ?

My motivation for this simpler case comes from the following: Let's consider our symplectic manifold to be the cotangent bundle and fix the fibers $T^*_{q_0} M, T^*_{q_1}M$. Now suppose we have an Hamiltonian flow $\phi^t$, from an hamiltonian function $H$, such that $\phi^1(T^*_{q_o}M)\pitchfork T^*_{q_1}M$. In the following paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0408280.pdf there is developed an isomorphism between the Floer Homology of the action functional whose critical points are orbits of our hamiltonian vector field and the corresponding Lagrangian functional on $TM$. Then one also defines here the index $\mu_{\Omega}(x)$ where $x$ is an orbit of $X_H$,and is able to prove its the same has the morse index of the action functional of the Lagrangian. And so for example in the case where $H(q,p)=\frac{1}{2}|p|^2$, and we get the Lagrangian $L(q,v)=\frac{1}{2}|v|^2$ we will get that $\mu_{\Omega}(x)$ will give us the index between $x(0)$ and $x(1)$. And so I am wondering if we look at the lagrangian intersection theory of $\phi^1(T^*_{q_0}M)$ and $T^*_{q_1}M$ and we looked at the intersection point that is $x(1)$, we will get that it's index is the same as $\mu_{\Omega}(x)$? If this were true it would be a nice geometrical interpretation of the index relating to geodesics and Jacobi fields.

Any insight is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The index of a critical point of the action functional cannot be defined. This is where Floer theory departs from the usual Morse theory, and Floer discusses it in the intro to his [original paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/journal-of-differential-geometry/volume-28/issue-3/Morse-theory-for-Lagrangian-intersections/10.4310/jdg/1214442477.full). I will try to do justice to this huge (but subtle) innovation.

In analogy with finite dimensional Morse theory, you could...

- Treat sections of $TM$ along a critical path $\gamma$ as the tangent space to the path space at $\gamma$: $T_{\gamma}(\Omega(L, L')) = \Gamma(\gamma^{\ast}TM)$. For Lagrangian boundary, restrictions are required on the sections near their endpoints.
- Compute the Hessian for the action functional at $\gamma$, which would split $\Gamma(\gamma^{\ast}TM)$ into positive and negative eigenspaces $E^{\pm}$. Assuming $\gamma$ is non-degenerate, there will be no $0$ eigenspace.
- Interpret $E^{\pm}$ as the tangent spaces to the ascending and descending manifolds for the critical point $\gamma$.

If this were possible, then we may seek to define the index to be the dimension of $E^{-}$ and count trajectories between critical points $\gamma_{0}, \gamma_{1}$ as points in the intersection of the ascending manifold for $\gamma_{0}$ with the descending manifold of $\gamma_{1}$.

This fails for a couple of reasons. First, ascending and descending manifolds are ill defined for analytical reasons (Palais-Smale). Second, both $E^{\pm}$ have infinite dimension. The miracle of Floer homology is that even though the indices of critical points are ill-defined, counting holomorphic strips with fixed ends $\gamma_{j}$ (same equation as one would solve for a Morse flow, but with endpoints determined) determines a Fredholm problem and the Fredholm index can be interpreted as an **index difference**, which is a finite integer.

The usual Morse homology can be recast in the Floer/Fredholm framework. See Schwarz's "Morse homology" book. But when you're able to express a Floer/Fredholm problems as a Morse problems with a well-defined gradient flow, there must be special circumstances.